# .Where inside a .Select , how to select only record that match the where clause:-

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following two statements :-

```
var isadminByuser = tms.SecurityRoles.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "administrator")
                                     .Select(a=>a.SecurityRoleUsers.Where(a2 => a2.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower()));

if (isadminByuser.Count() >= 1) { return true;}
```

&

```
var adminByGroup = tms.SecurityRoles.Where(a => a.Name == "Administrator")
                      .SingleOrDefault().Groups
                      .Select(a2 => a2.TMSUserGroups
                                      .Where(a3 => a3.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower()));

bool isadminByGroup = adminByGroup.Count() >= 1;
```

The first var `isadminByuser` will always have elements (will always be >=1), even if the where clause `a3.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower()))` is `false`, while the other var will have a count of zero is the where clause (`a3.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower())`) is false. So why will the first var never have a count of zero?

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question, but are your registrations case sensitive? Cause if so, any user who can register as `aDmINIstrATor` might become an administrator, according to your first statement.

Comment: These users are on active directory , so AD will not allow having two users with the same username but with different case...

Comment: your `.Count() >= 1` can be replaced with `.Any()` and may even make your program faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question asked is that you are selecting an `IQueryable<SecurityRoleUsers>` when you select 
    `a.SecurityRoleUsers.Where(a2 => a2.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower())`

which may or may not have a count of 0, but the containing query will return one of these `IQueryables` for each `SecurityRole` that matches `Name = "administrator"`, hence the count will always be 1+ if there is at least one matching `SecurityRole`

Update:

```
// first get SecurityRoles
bool isadminByuser = tms.SecurityRoles.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "administrator")
    // now you're only interested in the related SecurityRoleUsers
    .SelectMany( a => a.SecurityRoleUsers )
    // now check if any of the SecurityRoleUsers meet your criteria
    .Any( sru => sru.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower() );
```

Comment: but what i was thinking of, is that the select should only select the a.SecurityRoleUsers.Where(a2 => a2.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower()) for the related security role. and if there is no match for the "a2 => a2.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower()"., then the "var isadminByuser" should be empty ...

Comment: there are a few ways to go about doing what you want, but yours is not one of them.  check my updated answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Could you observe sql query differences from ms-sql-profiler

```
tms.SecurityRoles.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "administrator")
                                     .Select(a=>a.SecurityRoleUsers.Where(a2 => a2.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower()));

***

tms.SecurityRoles.Select(a=>a.SecurityRoleUsers.Where(a2 => a2.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower())).Where(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "administrator");
```